# Facebook Pixel is not firing through GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, tracking-pixel

For some reason my Facebook pixel doesn't fire when I install it through Tag manager. Here's how I've configured it:

[image: Pixel configuration]

In the debugger, the pixel doesn't appear. Only analytics tag show up. I actually have more tags installed like for heatmap but they don't show up here either, although they are working. So perhaps its the debugger that is not showing any tags except Google tags?

[image: GTM Debugger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these few things:

1. Make sure you published the tag after creating it
2. Make sure you're not using any "Ad Block" extension on the browser, if yes they also block GTM Scripts
3. Make sure you cleared the cache on your website. If you don't clear it, even if you have published the tag, it won't be firing when you browse the site afterward unless it's past cache expiry time.

Comment: It was the ad block. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad your issue is now resolved :)